# Why my main activity doesn't see my bottom navigation references?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to create bottom navigation bar.But I got a problem,the problem is that my MainActivity doesn't see my references(ic_home,ic_like,ic_settings).Thank you in advance!I really appreciate it!The first part of the code is from MainActivity,the second one is from nav_menu layout.

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.ic_home -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.ic_like -> makeCurrentFragment(likeFragment)
            R.id.ic_settings -> makeCurrentFragment(settingsFragment)
        }
        true
    }
```

That's from nav_menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="ic_like"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_like"
    android:title="Like"/>
<item
    android:id="ic_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home"/>
<item
    android:id="ic_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings"/>
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the nav_menu.xml id there an error for **id attribute** need to add following way:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_like"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_like"
    android:title="Like" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: You can accept n upvote the answer if you think it's correct.